# Do I need specify namespaces in xpath?

Tags: xpath

I am reading docs, and it's seems that namespaces are needed mostly for `xsd`-scheme and generation some other formats from XML. But I can't understand do I need to use them in XPATH. Nothing do not stop me to specify path to element without namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path without a namespace is a path to elements in the empty namespace. Nothing can stop you specifying a path without namespaces, but such a path only matches elements without namespaces.

For example, `/root/a/text()` returns `1`, but `/root/ns:a/text()` returns `2`:

```
<root xmlns:ns="some:namespace">
  <a>1</a>
  <ns:a>2</ns:a>
</root>
```

Both of the texts can be selected by `/root/*[local-name()='a']/text()`.

Comment: It there any way to not specify namespaces in xpath? I have a lot docs some of them have and some of them do not having namespaces.